# Beginner HTML/CSS Mistake

Tags: html, css

I'm taking a beginning web design class on Treehouse, and I have a question about centering a class in HTML with CSS, It's not coming out right, even though I have checked instructions. Can someone please look at this code and tell me what I've done wrong?

Here's the HTML:

```
<main class="flex">
  <div class="card">
    <h2>class="card-title">Background</h2>
```

And, Here's the CSS:

```
.card-title {
   text-align:center;
}
```

The output is like this: "class="card-title">Background"

---

I'm sure the answer is something super simple, because this is a simple course. But I'm just learning, and I'm rather nervous, so any help you can provide will be awesome!

Comment: `<h2 class="card-title">Background</h2>` - This will fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is here

```
<h2>class="card-title">Background</h2>
```

should be

```
<h2 class="card-title">Background</h2>
```

Answer (score 6):

You are closing the h2 too early. Also note that when you set a parent element to display: flex - all its children are affected - you may need to set a flex value on the h2  - or rethink the use of flex (thats is assuming your class of flex is to set the display:flex on the main element and its childrent - cards). If its as simple as centering the text, you won't need to use flex. And I am assuming that you are closing the `<main>` and the `div.card` as well..

It should be

```
<h2 class="card-title">Background</h2>
```